# How can I parse Amazon S3 logs with awk?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, awk, amazon-s3

`awk` requires you to provide a delimiter for each field, defaulting to a space character, but in the case of Amazon S3's server logs there are sometimes spaces inside each field. For instance, there's one inside the time field (eg: `[06/Feb/2014:00:00:38 +0000]` contains one) and could be one inside the key field also.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html

Is there a way to parse these simply in awk, or do I need to transform them somehow prior to feeding them through to awk?

If so, how could I go about that? I'm currently combining all of my log files:

`find . -type f -exec cat {} >> ../compiled.log \;`

and then running awk on that. Is there a way to transform via cat without breaking my key parameter, but still allowing that to be parsed by awk?

EDIT: I tried using gawk with FPAT but I'm not getting the same results as expected.

`Package gawk-3.1.7-10.10.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version`

My output:

```
$1 = <49a266cb12a607172a6adc1e468782f644b56ec22e3202cb735601b4e5524c08>
$2 = <BUCKET>
$3 = <[10/Apr/2015:19:56:22>
$4 = <+0000]>
$5 = <111.11.1111.11>
$6 = <->
$7 = <xxx>
$8 = <REST.GET.OBJECT>
$9 = <something.mp4>
$10 = <"GET>
$11 = </something.mp4>
$12 = <HTTP/1.1">
$13 = <403>
$14 = <AccessDenied>
$15 = <243>
 ...
```

$4 for me is '+0000' and $3 is missing the remainder of the date, so it doesn't appear to have worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GNU awk with `FPAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) comes to the rescue:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FPAT = "(\"[^\"]+\")|(\\[[^]]+\\])|([^ ]+)"} {
     for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) printf "$%d = <%s>\n", i, $i}' s3.log
```

**Output:** (with the sample log provided on linked ECS doc)

```
$1 = <79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be>
$2 = <mybucket>
$3 = <[06/Feb/2014:00:00:38 +0000]>
$4 = <192.0.2.3>
$5 = <79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be>
$6 = <3E57427F3EXAMPLE>
$7 = <REST.GET.VERSIONING>
$8 = <->
$9 = <"GET /mybucket?versioning HTTP/1.1">
$10 = <200>
$11 = <->
$12 = <113>
$13 = <->
$14 = <7>
$15 = <->
$16 = <"-">
$17 = <"S3Console/0.4">
$18 = <->
...
...
...
```

#### [Code Demo](http://ideone.com/KnFCLz)

Comment: `Package gawk-3.1.7-10.10.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version`

My output:

    $1 = <49a266cb12a607172a6adc1e468782f644b56ec22e3202cb735601b4e5524c08>
$2 = <BUCKET>
$3 = <[10/Apr/2015:19:56:22>
$4 = <+0000]>
$5 = <111.11.1111.11>
$6 = <->
$7 = <xxx>
$8 = <REST.GET.OBJECT>
$9 = <something.mp4>
$10 = <"GET>
$11 = </something.mp4>
$12 = <HTTP/1.1">
$13 = <403>
$14 = <AccessDenied>
$15 = <243>
    ...

$4 for me is '+0000' and $3 is missing the remainder of the date.

Comment: Trying to format it properly; let me edit the question, sorry!

Comment: Edited now with clarification. fwiw I also tried this with the same results as from the example and the same issue is there too, so it's not that my data is formatted differently.

Comment: When I do `awk --version` I get `GNU Awk 4.0.1`. What do you get?

Comment: Ah I am getting 3.1.7. I'm guessing to try removing that and reinstalling from source then perhaps?

Comment: Yes definitely `FPAT` is a modern GNU-awk feature, it probably came with gnu-awk 4+

Comment: Yes! I installed gawk 4.1.1 and it's working perfectly! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Also fwiw I followed the simple instructions here to configure and make it. Very easy: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/awk_environment.htm

Comment: Also be aware of shell expansion, with fish shell, I had to use `'\\\\['` to pass `\\[` to awk. Also awk would print a warning for only a single backslash.